# MySQL InnoDB cluster pricing

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustering, mysql-innodb-cluster

On https://www.mysql.com/products/community/, the InnoDB Cluster is listed as part of the MySQL community edition, but when clicking the "Download MySQL Community Edition" link and further, I end up on the NDB cluster documentation. So I'm confused about whether the InnoDB cluster is only availabla via the $5000 enterprise package, or if it's available for free too.

Have anyone looked into this, and know if the InnoDB Cluster is available for free?

Comment: I don't know what you clicked, but I don't land there. Try this link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474987 and click on "No thanks, just start my download" further down.

Comment: "Cluster" is ambiguous.  MySQL Cluster == NDB Cluster != InnoDB Cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from comments on Blog [Introducing MySQL InnoDB Cluster – MySQL HA: Out-of-Box, Easy to use High Availability](https://mysqlserverteam.com/introducing-mysql-innodb-cluster-mysql-ha-out-of-box-easy-to-use-high-availability/)

> Is this MySQL InnoDB Cluster – MySQL HA for Community Edition i.e
>   under GPL /OpenSource?

answer from Mike Zinner:

> (...)
>   yes, MySQL InnoDB Cluster is available in the Community
>   Edition and it is licensed under GPL. You can download the individual
>   components from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ You will need MySQL
>   Server, MySQL Shell and MySQL Router to build your MySQL InnoDB
>   Cluster (...)

Comment: I came across the same article before, but didn't read the comment. Thanks!